# Looking at the results of clustering algorithms on Protein Interaction Networks

Tags: bioinformatics, protein-database

I am working on a project involving the clustering of Protein Interaction Networks, having made several clustering algorithms on the graphs of interacting proteins, I am somewhat confused on how I would now go about seeing whether the clusters created are any *good* or *not*.

To put this into context protein interaction networks represent pairwise connections between proteins and isolating groups of interacting proteins that participate in the same biological processes or that perform together specific functions. This is significant as many proteins and interactions are unlabelled so inference to their function can be made if many labelled proteins for a certain are in one cluster.

Unlike typical supervised machine learning tasks where a labelled data set can show numbers of correct groupings or not, there is no precendent for *good* clusterings of proteins and their interaction, hypothetically a clustering where all proteins are in their one cluster are as good as one where all proteins are in one cluster (though there is no informational significance in this). There are of course no feature vectors for distance calculations either, only binary information whether one protein interacts with another or not, so this is quite difficult.

This problem is completely exploratory, and is hard to see whether a clustering is *significant* or just bogus.

Most academic papers use cluster analysis techniques to see how good *the clusters* and the *algorithms* are. ie. whether they are robust to edge deletion or node deletion, cluster correlation etc. I would like to see if there is any information one can fish out using protein databases, say input a large number of interactions (from one cluster) and see if the labelled ones have a tendency to be involved in the same metabolic process. If there is a significantly high number of proteins involved in one metabolic process one can surmise that the unlabelled proteins may be involved in a similar process or function, or similarly may be part of a protein domain or not.

I have just begun delving into bioinformatics and research in general so there is a very high chance that this has been done before and I haven't looked around extensively enough. If this is the case I would be grateful for links. I would appreciate any help possible, or ideas on how one could think about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question: you would like to know if your clustered protein interaction network identifies biologically relevant protein complexes...

I can think of three ways to do this:

1) Use the primary research literature. Take a cluster and search Pubmed for each member of the cluster and see if there are any reports of interactions with other members of the cluster. This will be time consuming but the most rigorous.

2) Submit each cluster to GO term enrichment analysis (David, funcassociate, etc.) or Pathway analysis (Kegg). If a cluster is "biologically" relevant it should be enriched for specific GO/Kegg terms. this will only work if most of your proteins have annotations.

3) Look at expression data. Biological complexes tend to have correlated gene expression patterns. There for the expression of a cluster should correlate with it members than non-members of the cluster.

I thought of a 4th:

4) Find homologs in an organism with a rich and deep annotation database and look for correlations there (yeast (*S. cerevisiae* or S. pombe*), fly (*D. melanogaster*), worm (*C elegans*), mouse, and human all have large protein interaction databases (i.e. Biogrid).

And a 5th:

5) Use genetic screen data. In this case genetic epistasis data will have distinct relationships within complexes. Proteins that are in the same complex will tend not to have a genetic interaction. While proteins in separate/independently acting complexes could have a genetic interaction component. See the work of Dr. Charles Boone (Univ. of Toronto) on how this can be modeled.

Final thoughts:

A little bit of domain-specific knowledge will go a long way to helping others believe your results. Do well-know/studied complexes form clusters? There has been a lot of work done in this field, Pubmed will be your friend. Start at Biogrid and work out from there.

Good luck

Comment: This is really late but thank you so much, especially for your friendly pointers, usually I'd get bashed for not knowing the enough biology to understand the terms, but you havent done so. I went with 1-2 of your suggestions initially, moving on to 3 and finally 4 for another piece of unrelated work.